# Does UITableView have an array property that holds all of the cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In one of my methods I want to iterate between the cells I have and perform changes on them, something like:

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in ___________) {

    cell.accessoryType = accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

so is there a property that will complete the ____________ ?

tnx!

Comment: Only the cells that are visible at a given moment exist at all.  Making changes to non-visible cells will have no effect.  Better to make this change to the AccessoryType in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and then reload the table (or the section) when something changes.

Comment: Iterate through your dataSource.

Answer (score 2):

There are only visible cells array `self.tableView.visibleCells`

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {

    cell.accessoryType = accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UITableView` itself doesn't know much about its content.  That's the job of it's `dataSource` delegate. See documentation for [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/)

Rather than thinking of the problem in a linear fashion.  Think of the problem as event driven.  If you want to modify the cell before it is displayed, you can check out [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) on the `UITableViewDelegate`

**edit**: given that you are looking to set the `accesoryType` you should probably try using [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).  Since that's where you're either dequeueing a reusable cell or manually `alloc] init]`'ing one .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: yourTableView.visibleCells

Answer (score 0):

[Chikabuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836420/chikabuz) is right.

**BUT** you should avoid making changes to the cells like this. Instead you should tell the tableView that your cells are updated and provide the changes in `- [id<UITableViewDataSource> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` like so:

```
- (IBAction)toggleSelecting:(id)sender {
    [[self tableView] setEditing:![[self tableView] isEditing] animated:YES];
//  or with custom use with own BOOL property:
//  [self setEditing:![self editing]];
    [[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[[self tableView] indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//  cell setup here...

//  or with custom use with own BOOL property:
//  if ([self editing]) {
    if ([[tableView] isEditing]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't get all cells in one array. But you can try to use the following:

```
let cellsArray: []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Your data source methods
    let cell = ......
    ....

    cellsArray.append(cell)
}
```

This way you can get array of cells after view loads. I think there is no any other way to do that.